# My query gives output for specific month but when I change the number in where clause it does not show any error instead in msg shows 0 row affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```sql
 select distinct t.DeviceID, t.HealthStatus, t.LastScanDate
   from DeviceScan t 
   
   inner join (
    select DeviceId, max(LastScanDate) as MaxDate
    from DeviceScan
    group by DeviceId
    ) 
    
    tm on t.DeviceId= tm.DeviceId and t.LastScanDate= tm.MaxDate
    where month (LastScanDate)='5'
```

Comment: Dumping some SQL in a question doesn't make it a question. What is your question? What are you asking? What isn't working with the SQL you have above?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: From the table devicescan I need to find out distinct device with their latest health status for a particular month. My query runs well just for month '5'.

Comment: The MONTH() function returns an int - why do you compare to a string? That is a bad habit to develop - relying on implicit conversion will eventually lead to problems.

Comment: what do i need to change in my query

Comment: If there is no data for month 6, then you just get no rows, not an error

Comment: To answer your question - apparently all your rows have a maximum value of LastScanDate  where the month is May. Without knowing what your goal is by "changing the number (month)", no one can offer useful suggestions. Perhaps you seek the last scan date per device in some particular month?

Comment: But there is data for month 3 or 4. Yet it dosen't show any table.

Comment: Then move the filter for month into the derived table (alias tm)

Comment: @SMor can we catch up through mail?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, learn to ask effective questions. In fact, your description does not really ask a question - it consists of a query only. As the comments indicate, add some descriptive information about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Here is my guess - based on my comment.

```
select t.DeviceID, t.HealthStatus, t.LastScanDate
   from dbo.DeviceScan t 
   inner join (
      select DeviceId, max(LastScanDate) as MaxDate
       from dbo.DeviceScan
      where MONTH( LastScanDate ) = 3
      group by DeviceId
    ) as tm 
 on t.DeviceId = tm.DeviceId and t.LastScanDate = tm.MaxDate;
```

Notice the changes I made. I removed DISTINCT since it is probably not needed. Stop throwing such things into a query in a blind effort to "fix things".  I added (and assumed) the schema name to your table - that is a best practice.

With the filter in the derived table (tm), the query will only consider rows where the month is (now) March. There are more efficient ways to filter for a specific month but that is a different question. The MAX aggregate then finds the maximum value for that set of rows.